# How to extract values from string lists in R?

Tags: r, string, extract

I want to extract the X-squared value and p-value (number only) from three string vectors.

```
smr.text1

[1] ""                                                              
[2] "\tPearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction"
[3] ""                                                              
[4] "data:  data$parasite and data$T1"                              
[5] "X-squared = 0.017361, df = 1, p-value = 0.8952"                
[6] ""    

smr.txt2    

[1] ""                                                              
[2] "\tPearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction"
[3] ""                                                              
[4] "data:  data$parasite and data$T2"                              
[5] "X-squared = 2.5679e-32, df = 1, p-value = 1"                   
[6] ""  

smr.text3

[1] ""                                                              
[2] "\tPearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction"
[3] ""                                                              
[4] "data:  data$parasite and data$T3"                              
[5] "X-squared = 0.17857, df = 1, p-value = 0.6726"                
[6] ""
```

It was easy for me to extract those values from the first string vector using indexing numbers:

```
> c1 <- as.numeric(str_sub(smr.txt1[5], 13, 20))

> c1
```

> [1] 0.017361

```
> p1 <- as.numeric(str_sub(smr.txt1[5], -6))

> p1
```

> [1] 0.8952

But in the second string vector I can't really do the same since it's a scientific number. Also I could do the same with the third string vector, but is there a better way, for example using a loop to extract these values only and put them in the same data frame? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask why you need to extract numbers from printed output of e.g. `chisq.test` rather than just extracting them from the test object itself? See the examples in the help file `?chisq.test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not what you've asked, it looks as though you used `capture.output(.)` to capture those strings. Instead of trying to extract the strings from the captured output, I suggest you get the *real numbers* from the objects themselves.

```r
M <- as.table(rbind(c(762, 327, 468), c(484, 239, 477)))
dimnames(M) <- list(gender = c("F", "M"),
                    party = c("Democrat","Independent", "Republican"))
Xsq <- chisq.test(M)
names(Xsq)
# [1] "statistic" "parameter" "p.value"   "method"    "data.name" "observed"  "expected"  "residuals" "stdres"   
Xsq[c("statistic","p.value")]
# $statistic
# X-squared 
#  30.07015 
# $p.value
# [1] 2.953589e-07
```

Since you mention having a list of these, it's easy to work with that as well. For instance, if you have a list of test results as in

```r
Xsq2 <- lapply(list(M, M), chisq.test)
Xsq2
# [[1]]
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
# data:  X[[i]]
# X-squared = 30.07, df = 2, p-value = 2.954e-07
# [[2]]
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
# data:  X[[i]]
# X-squared = 30.07, df = 2, p-value = 2.954e-07
lapply(Xsq2, `[`, c("statistic", "p.value"))
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$statistic
# X-squared 
#  30.07015 
# [[1]]$p.value
# [1] 2.953589e-07
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$statistic
# X-squared 
#  30.07015 
# [[2]]$p.value
# [1] 2.953589e-07
```

which can be easily converted into a `data.frame` with:

```r
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(Xsq2, `[`, c("statistic", "p.value")))
#   statistic      p.value
# 1  30.07015 2.953589e-07
# 2  30.07015 2.953589e-07
```

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly from capture.output(). I solved a similar problem with this function before and thought I could do it again, but guess I was overthinking. Simply getting the values from the objects is much more convenient!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `str_sub` (which is position based and it wouldn't work when the start/end positions are not constant as in example 2) we may use regex lookaround to extract for p-value substring and the digits with `.` that follows (`str_extract`)

```
library(stringr)
f1 <- function(x, categ ="p-value") {
     as.numeric(str_extract(x, 
        glue::glue("(?<={categ} \\= )[0-9.]+(e-[0-9]*)?")))
     }
```

-testing

```
> f1("X-squared = 0.017361, df = 1, p-value = 0.8952")
[1] 0.8952
> f1("X-squared = 0.017361, df = 1, p-value = 0.8952", "X-squared")
[1] 0.017361
> f1("X-squared = 2.5679e-32, df = 1, p-value = 1")
[1] 1
> f1("X-squared = 2.5679e-32, df = 1, p-value = 1", "X-squared")
[1] 2.5679e-32
> f1("X-squared = 0.17857, df = 1, p-value = 0.6726")
[1] 0.6726
> f1("X-squared = 0.17857, df = 1, p-value = 0.6726", "X-squared")
[1] 0.17857
```

---

Another option would be to convert to `data.frame` with column names as 'X-squared', 'p-value', 'df' and then extract the column values

```
f2 <- function(x, categ = "p-value") {

   x1 <-  gsub(",\\s*", "\n", gsub("\\s*=\\s*", ":", x))
   type.convert(as.data.frame(read.dcf(textConnection(x1))),
       as.is = TRUE)[[categ]]


}
```

-testing

```
> f2("X-squared = 0.17857, df = 1, p-value = 0.6726", "X-squared")
[1] 0.17857
> f2("X-squared = 0.017361, df = 1, p-value = 0.8952")
[1] 0.8952
> f2("X-squared = 0.017361, df = 1, p-value = 0.8952", "X-squared")
[1] 0.017361
>  f2("X-squared = 2.5679e-32, df = 1, p-value = 1")
[1] 1
> f2("X-squared = 2.5679e-32, df = 1, p-value = 1", "X-squared")
[1] 2.5679e-32
> f2("X-squared = 0.17857, df = 1, p-value = 0.6726")
[1] 0.6726
> f2("X-squared = 0.17857, df = 1, p-value = 0.6726", "X-squared")
[1] 0.17857
```

---

It is not clear why we need to convert the output `list` output from `chisq.test` to string for extraction i.e. from the output of `chisq.test`, it is easier to extract with `$` or `[[`

```
M <- as.table(rbind(c(762, 327, 468), c(484, 239, 477)))
dimnames(M) <- list(gender = c("F", "M"),
                    party = c("Democrat","Independent", "Republican"))
Xsq <- chisq.test(M)
Xsq$p.value
#[1] 2.953589e-07
Xsq$statistic[["X-squared"]]
[1] 30.07015
```

Comment: I am quite a new R coder and sometimes afraid of writing functions... but your function is very helpful, thanks a lot!